# Getting “There were deployment errors” In Visual Studio 2017 With Xamarin / HAXM

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, emulation

I just installed Visual Studio 2017 Community on my Windows 7 64bit laptop.  When I installed Visual Studio, I included the Xamarin components option so everything should be installed properly.

I created a new cross platform Xamarin project and I'm trying to run it with the default emulator.  The project is just what VS creates and I've added nothing.  So it should pop up in the emulator with "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!". I get the following errors below.  Can you please help me understand what I need to do to get this working?

Thanks, Andy

[image: Deployment Errors]
[image: Emulator]
[image: AVD Setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled Visual Studio, restarted and then reinstalled and it now seems to at least bring up the Android emulator, albeit very slow.

Comment: Try out x86, its supposed to be faster. And make sure that you got hardware accelereation installed. Btw, i got the same issue - dosnet start but i usually compile to my phone anyways

Comment: oh, and check "genymotion" its like the best emulator ever

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error message, then HAXM is probably not installed.

Please check this document: [Install HAXM](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-emulator/android-sdk-emulator/#install-haxm).

Answer (score 0):

check your laptop processor,
AMD does not support Intel HAXM.
And some old Intel processor also does't support Intel HAXM.

If those are the issue you have to work with ARM emulators.